# scaled down divs take up full space and you can scroll thru empty space

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have **divs that are scaled down to 0** and at that point all is good. **once they get sized up to anything more than 0 they take up full space** - even more when they are like 0.0001 they allready take up the full space they would at the end of the animation (which takes 10s just for demo purposes)

can anybody make theese divs take up only as much space as they actually do or at least when the other divs are not loaded in yet they shouldt make a scrollable empty area. like i want the containing div to gradually resize / grow with the content that is in it like if i have 3 divs its gonna be the size that any normal html element would have when 3 of those divs are inside. and as more appear i would like it to grow.

please no jquery

pay attention to how it is **instantly scrollable after beginning of animation**

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item")
      , t = 0;
    items.forEach(function (i) {
      i.style.animationDelay = t + "s";
      t = t + 2;
    });
    var imgs = [];
    items.forEach(function (itm) {
      let image = itm.children[0]
      image.src = image.getAttribute('lazy-src');
      image.onload = () => {
        image.style.opacity = "1";
      };
    });
```

```css
body {
    background: #212121;
}
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item {
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 150px;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 1%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background: #191919;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    animation: 10s loadInItems ease forwards;
}
.item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes loadInItems {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="list">
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/Endgame-movie-cover.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Unstoppable_dvd_movie_cover_snipes.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://cdn4.hiphoplead.com/static/2008/02/street-kings.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://www.cinematerial.com/media/posters/md/hh/hhy018qz.jpg?v=1462117460"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6M7momC3yKVexsaIyT4EjIals6x7d5Z_h3bF5gwxyPiAyzpVk"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSzmuhqg42zthBrJ0kZoP887ZrTIW3eu2llBSCs3etXqMIG9gT-w"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c5/Sniper-3-movie-cover-1.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://waytooindie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/jurassic-park-movie-cover.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/8900000/death-note-movie-1-cover-death-note-the-movie-8968544-349-500.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://www.impawards.com/2014/posters/ouija.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://justcreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/suspician-movie-poster-5.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/cc/09/8f/cc098f8ca9d5b7815212671c0c251fa1.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://orig13.deviantart.net/4d95/f/2011/007/b/2/child__s_play_movie_cover_3_by_designerdude0326-d36mlvh.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/73/DVD_cover_of_the_movie_Secret_Cutting.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/custom/Blog_Images/guardians-of-the-galaxy-movie-poster1.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e9/20/a9/e920a9c97b5f7d9b5005001c748bed44.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://www3.images.coolspotters.com/wallpapers/99326/the-cat-in-the-hat-mobile-wallpaper.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://www.companyfolders.com/blog/media/2015/04/dracula-untold-poster.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYRkyEL1GlSh-8Zt7x79ZN8Lnma-4aYrg_MS9VPxGLUm4EiMIhAQ"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f9/a0/e3/f9a0e397b6d5aab658082a3a81ebe82e.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQixcjxVaC35V7WkV_tR5Z19BaBGdKxKWODBxwSQa00lE4bpSF6"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="https://marketplace.canva.com/MACFJIeg3d4/1/0/thumbnail_large/canva-chilling-car-park-movie-poster--MACFJIeg3d4.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/08/17/19/2B71134000000578-0-image-a-1_1439834864648.jpg"> </div>
         <div class="item"> <img lazy-src="http://graphicdesignjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/choose-movie-poster.jpg"> </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `transform: scale` is that it has no affect on DOM layout; the item "takes" up the original size, so no level of flexbox shrinkage is going to make it size to fit. If, however, you animate based on `width` and `height` instead, the actual layout will adjust as it animates:

```
.item {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 1%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background: #191919;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    animation: 10s loadInItems ease forwards;
}

@keyframes loadInItems {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 150px;
        height: 210px;
    }
}
```

I played with making these changes, and the content only scrolls down once the items are present. There is jankiness on when images end up wrapping to the next line, but you can probably work around that by having containers with fixed widths.

Comment: yep. that works. but notice how in my version divs just load in where they're supposed to be and resize equally upwards and downwards wahile  your design fixes the scrolling problem it also makes images spaz out when they are loading in (on every last image in the line / row). is there some other way? maybe like removing all images and then appending them one by one?

Comment: My suggestion is to place the images in containers that have fixed widths.